# finalPrice with no currency and 2 decimal points (for rich snippets)

Tags: magento-1.9

So on the product page (view.phtml)  I had:

```
<div class="no-display" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
<span itemprop="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()); ?></span>
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
```

Which give me the result of eg €70.30

But for rich snippet the currency has to be declared separately

So i used the code:

```
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>"/>
<span itemprop="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), false, false); ?></span>
```

Which give the the Currency separately from the Price but the price is now not rounded so I get eg: 70.30132312323

How do I get the price (with out the currency) to 2 decimal points?

Edit: just to clarify, there are 2 store fronts with different currencies, so if you just call the base price it will give the wrong value for one of the store fronts ( eg you get 64.99 instead of 70.30)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put following code:

```
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>"/>
<span itemprop="price"><?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice(); ?></span>
```

If, for some reason, you still get too many decimals, you can use:

```
<span itemprop="price"><?php echo round($_product->getFinalPrice(), 2); ?></span>
```

Comment: While that does show the price in 2 decimal places, it shows the base currency price and not the price of the currency for the store front, so it is show 64.99 and not 70.30

Comment: OK, i just changed my code to:  <span itemprop="price"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice(), 2, false, false); ?>

Answer (score 0):

The price is stored in the Mage registry already rounded.  You can access the price like this:

```
<?php Mage::registry('product')->getFinalPrice(); ?>
```

Comment: While that does show the price in 2 decimal places, it shows the base currency price and not the price of the currency for the store front, so it is show 64.99 and not 70.30